# Что выбрать - конкуррентность, параллелизм или новый поток?

Tags: python, многопоточность, asyncio, multiprocessing

У меня есть программа. Она состоит из 5 частей. Чтобы не вдаваться в подробности проведу аналогию: 1 часть флудит в консоль каждые 0.5 секунд, 2 часть редактирует текстовый файл каждую секунду, 3 часть что-то еще каждые 10 секунд и так далее.

Иными словами в программе совершаются разные действия с разными промежутками времени. Все 5 частей программы работают без перерыва, пока пользователь не закроет программу.

Что выбрать для реализации подобного? Потоки, несмотря на GIL, меня вполне устраивают. Однако может есть более красивый и удобный способ? Я смотрю в сторону asyncio и конкурентности, но мне кажется, что это не то. Создавать новый поток?

Отсюда вопрос: что выбрать? Использовать для этого потоки, asyncio или создавать новые потоки?

Comment: если "таска тяжелая" (в моем понимании, редактирование файла таким является), то его хорошо в отдельный поток. Если же задача "легкая", то можно и в основном потоке все делать (то есть, обычный while true, который проверяет текущее время, рассчитывает, сколько до следующей и спит расчитаное время).

Comment: А можно конкретнее? Почему для ресурсоемких задач поток лучше, а не процесс или корунтина? И почему обратное тоже верно?

Comment: процесс в принципе это тот же поток (а иногда это практически одно и тоже). Но у процесса есть один супер большой плюс - если что то пойдет не так (например, задача скушала всю память), то процесс легко прибить и перезапустить. А вот поток- нет.

Comment: Зависит от конкретных задач. В частности, задачи «флудит в консоль» и «редактирует ... файл» освобождают GIL на время своей работы, так что он здесь не мешается. А вот задача «что-то еще» может всё испортить...

Comment: Что значит освобождают GIL? Что такое GIL знаю, но не слышал про освобождение. Где можно почитать про это?